# Spring MVC 3 with Dojo's QueryReadStore

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo, spring-roo

I have a Spring project based on a Spring Roo template. I want to implement an autocomplete in a combobox. Afer hours of researching I found that using dojox.data.QueryReadStore is my best option, since I will be fetchin data from server side and only want a short list of options as a result.

My problem is that I'm still new to implementing dojo in Spring and can't figure out how to connect my comboBox to the QueryReadStore. The idea is to call a controller's method and fetch the results as the user types into de comboBox.

**Edit:**

```
var store = dojox.data.queryReadStore({url:'/.../something'})
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : ${fn:escapeXml(fieldname)}, widgetType: 'dijit.form.ComboBox', 
        widgetAttrs : {                   
            hasDownArrow : false,
            store:store,
            searchAttr:"name",
            autoComplete:false,
        }

    }));
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
Class controller{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<String> someMethod(@RequestParam("name") String queryString){
        //use queryString here
        return listOfStrings;
    }
}
```

Any tips or ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

queryReadstore will accept a parameter as url:giveyour url here

```
var store = dojox.data.QueryReadStore({url:http:// ... .. /someString})
var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
            id: "stateSelect",
            name: "state",
            value: "CA",
            store: stateStore,
            searchAttr: "name"
        }, "stateSelect");
```

now map this url to your controller either in dispatcher-servlet.xml or using annotations.

```
@Controller
Class controller{
    @RequestMapping("someString")
    public void someMethod(@RequestParam("name") String queryString){
        //use queryString here
        out.write(response in JSON string format);
    }
}
```

- note the parametername in @RequestParam(parametername) this will be same as the searchAttr in filtering select attribute.

Comment: I added some code. I'm using a ComboBox instead of a FilteringSelect but that doesn't change the problem. With the line that you gave me I get: TypeError: dojox.data.queryReadStore is not a function

Comment: I don't know if the modules are case sensitive or not (I suppose they are), but that means you need to use dojox.data.QueryReadStore.
Are you sure you are importing the QueryReadStore (with dojo.require) yet?

Comment: Yes Dimitri, I agree to it, was not uding any IDE while i wrote that code so missed the syntax :) corrected it now.

Comment: I have some improvements! Also had to add the dependency to the pom. Added the controller method I have to the post. I get it to return a list of Strings: ["aaa","abc"]. But the comboBox doesn't show any changes :(

Comment: the format of your response is not correct the correct format should be

{
 "items": [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "aaa",
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "abc",
 }],
 "label": "name",
 "identifier": "id"
}

also put some logs / sysouts in controller if you are able to hit the controller correctly.

Comment: I had to add a JSON parser to get the list like you described and it worked! Thanks :)